# FCC / Local Weather App / JSON information not displaying info from the OpenWeather API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, weather

I am doing the freeCodeCamp Local Weather App Zipline Challenge, and got to the part where I have extracted my location using an IP-Location API, and am supposed to use the location with the Open Weather API to get information about the local weather.

I've done this successfully and opening the JSON links in a new tab in my Browser(Chrome) displays the JSON with all the objects/arrays/info I need/etc.

However, were I to try and log this info to the console or change an html element's contents with specific information from the callback info, I get nothing. Not even any errors.

I did some research and tried to use http instead of https on my codepen, but that didn't solve the problem. I also tried going through some Youtube tutorials, but nobody else encountered the issue.

I have included code snippets with all of my code from the codepen(NOTE: I removed the api key for the local weather app)

Here are some useful links:
1. The challenge info itself: https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/show-the-local-weather
2.The IP API I used to get my location: http://ip-api.com/
3.The Open Weather API: https://openweathermap.org/current#geo

EDIT: To make my question more clear: Why does the info I get from the API not display in the HTML elements specified in the jQuery function?

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
        var city;
        var countryCode;
        
        $.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json",function(data2){
            city = data2.city; 
            countryCode = data2.countryCode;
            
          var api = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+city+","+countryCode+"&APPID=MYKEYGOESHERE";
          $.getJSON(api, function(data3){        
            $("cityName").html(data3.city);
            $("temperature").html(data3.temp);
            $("weather").html(data3.weather[0].description);
          });
      });
  });
```

```css
body{
  color:#FFF;
  background-color: #f4495d;
}
.mainContainer{
  margin:7% auto;
  background-color: #ce2336;
  width:50%;
}

h2{
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 180%;
}

p{
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 150%;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContainer">
  <h2>The Local Weather APP</h2>
   <div class="coordinates">
     <p id="data">something something</p>
  </div>
   <div class="one-Third">
     <p id="cityName">YourCity</p>
   </div>
   <div class="one-Third">
     <p id="temperature">TheTemperature</p>
   </div>
   <div class="one-Third">
     <p id="weather">TheWeather</p>
   </div>
   <img src="#">
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand, what is the question ?

Comment: Why is the data that I get from the API not displayed in the HTML elements specified in the jQuery function?

Answer (score 0):

okay based on the comment, you need to fill the html that you are creating, to do this, you have to put "`#`" character in order to fill a specific element, so your code should be

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var city;
    var countryCode;

    $.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json",function(data2){
        city = data2.city; 
        countryCode = data2.countryCode;

      var api = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+city+","+countryCode+"&APPID=MYKEYGOESHERE";
      $.getJSON(api, function(data3){        
        $("#cityName").text(data3.city);
        $("#temperature").text(data3.temp);
        $("#weather").text(data3.weather[0].description);
      });
  });
```

});

Comment: I actually fixed this quite a while ago, having noticed it, but the data is still not being inserted, I guess I'll just have to revert to vanilla JS and do it with the normal .ajax call. Thanks for the effort though :)

Comment: Glad to hear that, and im sorry if this is not fixed your problem